# VSCode: No module found even after installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

No matter whatever module I install, in VSCode, it just shows that no module is found.

[image]

If the requirement is already satisfied then why still not found? Please let me know...

**Edit1:**

Here's the pip version which is `3.10` but the version of python it is showing me is `3.9.7`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you check which python and from which location it is picking python interpreter?
Suggestion is , create virtual env and do your code

Comment: Make sure your pip is the same pip as your python. To make sure, check both with `--version` flag.

Comment: You can ensure you're running pip with the same python by invoking it as `python -m pip ...` instead of `pip ...`.

Comment: Hey @h4z3 can you please check my edit?

Comment: @Abhaysalvi As AKX said, you can use pip as `python -m pip` (pip will be executed by whatever `python` is - thus for sure correct version with anything else executed with `python`). It seems you somehow got only 3.10's pip added to PATH, not the python itself. And as John said, I'd recommend you look at virtual environments to better sort your projects. Activated venv activates command aliases and `pip` will match the selected `python`, no matter whether you have one, two, or ten versions in your system

Comment: just saw @h4z3 post the same as my answer just as I posted it, oof haha. But definitely seems to either be not added to path, or perhaps added with another name e.g. `python3` instead of `python`

Answer (score 1):

Although you have selected the python310 environment in the third picture, it has no influence at all. Without the activate command such as `Activate.ps1`, `activate.bat`, it will automatically search the python and pip depending on the system environment variable of Path.

Obviously, from the second picture, we can know the pip and the python were not in the same environment. Either you mess up the order in the `Path`, or your python3.9.7 without pip installed.

[image]

Such as this can cause the python and pip not in the same environment.

You can move down the python3.9.7 in the Path to avoid it. But it's recommended to create a virtual environment. If you don't know how to create a virtual environment you can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment).

Answer (score 0):

You have two versions of python installed, and you have used pip in one of them but not the one you are running.

if you want to ensure that you are running pip for the correct version, you can run:

```
python -m pip install pynput
```